# How can I get into the C++mode automatically when open .h files?

Tags: emacs

How can I get into the C++mode automatically when  open .h files?

I uses emacs23.2 in fedura6.

I open .cpp file use C-x C-f  xxx.h .

Answer (score 3):

```
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.h$" . c++-mode) auto-mode-alist))
```

Answer (score 3):

probably this will be better aesthetically?

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist (cons "\\.h\\'" 'c++-mode))
```